# Can't display anything on 16x2 display(I2C Board) with nodemcu?

Tags: esp8266, i2c, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to display text on 16x2 display using a Nodemcu board. I have connected the display using a serial connector to board like below.

- Vcc => 3v Pin
- GND => G pin
- SCL => D1 pin
- SDA => D2 pin

This is the code I have tried

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F,16,2); // set the LCD address to 0x3F for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
lcd.init(); // initialize the lcd
lcd.backlight();
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Hello world");
lcd.setCursor(1,0);
lcd.print("ESP32 I2C LCD");

}

void loop() {}
```

I was able to compile this code successfully and save it to the board using Arduino IDE, but nothing display on the screen, the backlights are working fine.

Does anyone know what is going on?

the example I followed https://www.instructables.com/id/Interface-LCD-Using-NodeMCU/

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the contrast / brightness of the display (potentiometer on the board)? The text might be there but not really visible.

Comment: ohh, did not try

Comment: Ohh problem was 3V supply is not enough to display the text, after change Vcc pin to 5V pin I can see the Text,

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
lcd.backlight();
```

to

```
lcd.setBacklight((uint8_t)1);
```